# Laravel 5 insert works without $fillable

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, model, fillable

I have a Laravel application made by someone else.

In the controller I have this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Result;

class StoreInDB extends Controller
{
    function store($uuid, $session){
        // Insert data
        $r = new Result;
        if($r->updateOrInsert(['user_id' => $uuid], ['user_id' => $uuid, 'answers' => $session])){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Model Result I have this:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Result extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Why does it work? There is no $fillable to tell which column can be used to insert.

Datas are inserted. But why? The only issue I have is that created_at and updated_at are null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[updateOrInsert](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert) uses the query builder and not eloquent, therefore it wont trigger model events or respect the `guarded` or `fillable` properties and won't populate the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns.

If you want to use the mentioned eloquent features you should use [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_updateOrCreate).

Something like this:

```
public function store($uuid, $session)
{
    if (null === Result::updateOrCreate(['user_id' => $uuid], ['answers' => $session])) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note that `updateOrCreate` returns a model instance and `updateOrInsert` returns a `boolean`.

**[updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts)**:

> Occasionally, you may need to update an existing model or create a new
> model if no matching model exists. Like the `firstOrCreate` method,
> the `updateOrCreate` method persists the model, so there's no need to
> manually call the save method.
>
> In the example below, if a flight exists with a `departure` location
> of `Oakland` and a `destination` location of `San Diego`, its `price`
> and `discounted` columns will be updated. If no such flight exists, a
> new flight will be created which has the attributes resulting from
> merging the first argument array with the second argument array:

```
$flight = Flight::updateOrCreate(
    ['departure' => 'Oakland', 'destination' => 'San Diego'],
    ['price' => 99, 'discounted' => 1]
);
```

**[updateOrInsert:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-or-insert)**

> Sometimes you may want to update an existing record in the database or
> create it if no matching record exists. In this scenario, the
> `updateOrInsert` method may be used. The `updateOrInsert` method
> accepts two arguments: an array of conditions by which to find the
> record, and an array of column and value pairs indicating the columns
> to be updated.
>
> The `updateOrInsert` method will attempt to locate a matching database
> record using the first argument's column and value pairs. If the
> record exists, it will be updated with the values in the second
> argument. If the record can not be found, a new record will be
> inserted with the merged attributes of both arguments:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->updateOrInsert(
        ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'name' => 'John'],
        ['votes' => '2']
    );
```

Comment: You're a genius, how can you know these things. I read a lot of documentation about Laravel and i did not find out. Thank you very much